# Search service application log files consuming disk space

Tags: 2013, search, service, iis7

is it okay to delete the log files created by search service application? Currently it consumes most of the  disk space of our drive which we need to get rid off.

The Logs files are located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\Applications\Search\Nodes\66D397\IndexComponent2\storage\data\SP5dc9e9ab6d5d.5.I.0.0\ms\%default
```

[image]

Any help and suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are **not** log files, it's your actual search index. It is recommended to move the index to it's own drive so that the index (or any other log files) cannot consume all disk space on the C drive.

Moving the index means that you need to clone the search topology and then move the clone to another drive. This is kind of a complicated procedure as you have to do everything using PowerShell.

My best advice is to read about the procedure and if possible, test this on a test environment before doing in production.

[Manage the index component in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj862355.aspx#Index_Comp_Move)

[SharePoint 2013: Moving the Index Partition to the another drive on same/another server](http://strangelittletech.blogspot.se/2014/06/sharepoint-2013-moving-index-partition.html)